# Difference between SetBinding() and Property={Binding Path}

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a customized control with one DependencyProperty named "VerticalOffset" which has a public getter and a private setter.Then I tried to bind it to a ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset which is a part of its template.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl));

    public double HorizontalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty); }
        private set
        {
            SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I have tried two solutions to this, but things went strange.

1. Using the code-behind, everything is OK.

   ```
   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
   {
       PART_ScrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)GetTemplateChild("PART_ScrollViewer");
       this.SetBinding(VerticalOffsetProperty, new Binding("VerticalOffset") { Source = PART_ScrollViewer });
   }
   ```
2. Using the XAML,there's an error:

   > Cannot set property 'VerticalOffset','cus it has no accessible setter.

   ```
   VerticalOffset="{Binding VerticalOffset,ElementName=PART_ScrollViewer}"
   ```

So, here is the problem:

### **What's the difference between these two solutions and why does the 2nd one not work?**

Comment: Which VS version do you have? Mine doesn't abbreviate "because" properly.

Comment: @AustinMullins : vs2013, using.net4.0.

Comment: Ok. Did you mean VerticalOffset in your first code block?

Comment: @AustinMullins:Yes,the 1st is in code behind,the 2nd is in xaml.

Comment: No, I mean the first block where you posted the HorizontalOffset dependency property.

Comment: I'm confused... you created a readonly property and then tried to change it's value?

Comment: @AndrewCounts It's a ... exception just like a rabbit hole...I found that the binding system may have a very high priority which can ignore the 'private' key-word and set such a 'readonly' property's value.

Comment: I'm not sure that GetTemplateChild does exactly the same thing of ElementName in binding. Try to use ElementName with SetBinding, then see if it works. I think you should use RelativeSource in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all,I tried SetBinding() and SetValue() methods outside the definition class scope to validate my suppose that the private setter doesnt make sense in code level.The result shows that the property value is changed by directly using SetBinding() or SetValue() method no matter its Property setter is private or public.

But,if we use a private setter,any value setting in xaml is prohibited which means we cannot use VerticalOffset="20" or VerticalOffset="{Binding Path}" syntax.

Besides,I also tried those WPF core readonly property such as ScrollViewer.VerticalOffseProperty,the result is very interesting.When I tried to SetValue() it told me that

> Error: The readonly VerticalOffsetProperty cannot be modified without an authorization key.

And then the SetBinding() method return another result

> Error: "VerticalOffset" is readonly which cannot be bound.

### My suppose

> 1.Since we define a DependencyProperty,we have the total rights by using SetValue() or SetBinding() method to modify it in code level and the Wrapper is ignored 'cus it is only a lite interface for common use just like a CLR property.So that's why when we use a private setter,the xaml will fail.
>
> 2.Maybe,the developer of .net have found these potential risks,so they use some validating methods to avoid invalid changes.